# Does the Warlock's Expanded Spell List from their patron only add it to their list of options, not their spells known?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, warlock, spellcasting

> **Expanded Spell List**
>   The Fiend lets you choose from an expanded list of spells when you learn a warlock spell. The following spells are added to the warlock *spell list* for you.

Should this mean, that unlike the Cleric, a Warlock does not gain the Patron spells *in addition* to the spells known?

So a 1st level Cleric with 16 Wis can prepare 4 spells, *plus* 2 from the Domain, but a Warlock only knows 2 spells, no matter what?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## **Yes**

As it is stated in the text:

> ### Expanded Spell List
>
> The Fiend lets you choose from an expanded list of spells **when you learn a warlock spell**. The following spells are added to the warlock spell list for you.

I.E. whenever you learn a spell, you have extra choices. You don't have extra spells known.